# EditText will lose it's value upon scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I've been searching in the net for the possible answer. I found one but it will keep on changing it's value upon scrolling. I don't know which part of my code that makes it changing. I have an `EditText` and `TextView` in my customized `ListView`. `TextView` will hold the list of student from the database and `EditText` will have the user to input the score of corresponding student. Here's my code

```
public class RecordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Context context;
      private final String[] values;
      String value;

      public RecordAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.row1, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
      }       

      @Override
      public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

          value = "0";
          final ViewHolder holder;
          if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, null);

                holder.scoreEditText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scores);
                holder.nameTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            }

          holder.nameTextView.setText(value);
           holder.nameTextView.setText(values[position]);
           holder.scoreEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int before, int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        value = holder.scoreEditText.getText().toString();
                        value = s.toString();

                    }
                });

            return convertView;


      }


        static class ViewHolder{
            public TextView nameTextView;
            public EditText scoreEditText;

        }


    }
```

Please help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Every time a row is updated, `getView()` is called. And you set the text back to 0 by using `value = "0"`, thus the update to the String value in `afterTextChanged` is not applied. Fix this declaring calling the String text as global like: `String value = "0"` in your adapter class and remove `value = "0"` from your `getView()` method.

Other then that,

- Remove `value = s.toString();`
- Move `value = holder.scoreEditText.getText().toString();` to `onTextChanged(..)`
- Add the following to your adapter class:

  `public int getViewTypeCount() {
      return getCount();
  }`

  `public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      return position;
  }`

Comment: Hi, I followed what you said but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Try removing this line: value = s.toString();

Comment: Some of the field will remain it's value , others will still change as I scroll up and down the listview.

Comment: implemmenting getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int position)  work for me

Answer (score 0):

It isn't recommended to put EditText inside a listView, since it causes changes to the listView itself (because of the keyboard).

Instead you should use simple TextView, and if you wish to edit there something, either use a dialog with it or a new activity that allows you to edit the value.

in any case, if you still wish to have EditText in the listView, you should save the data it holds each time you change its text (note that for "afterTextChanged" you didn't save the data into your "values" variable), and restore it on getView .

You should also consider using "onTextChanged" instead of "afterTextChanged"

Comment: I already consider onTextChanged as what Aashir said but still it doesn't work. Do you have any idea or a sample code to make this work?

Comment: Well, anyway. i will consider your advice. i think it will work. Thank you.

Comment: ok, i think i've found one problem: you called addTextChangedListener , but you didn't remove it at any other time, so you add more and more listeners. you should either remove it each time, or you should put a generic listener on the creation of the view.

Comment: What do you mean by putting a generic listener on the view? I'm sorry I am still a newbie in android

Comment: it has nothing to do with Android. it's about java and code design. what i've suggested that you can do is to put the listener in the block of "if (convertView == null)" , and in order to access the data, always use the holder in the "onTextChanged" method (and never use the "position" parameter there, since it changes). that's why i called it "generic", since it should work for any holder. this way you also avoid GC since you don't need to call "new" for each call to "getView" .